# Using NSUserDefaults to save Region of an MKMapView

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, nsuserdefaults

Whenever my map view region changes, I'm saving the center and span values to NSUserDefaults so when the app is opened again it will be in the same place.

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, regionDidChangeAnimated animated: Bool) {
    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    defaults.setValue(myMapView.centerCoordinate.latitude, forKey: "lat")
    defaults.setValue(myMapView.centerCoordinate.longitude, forKey: "long")
    defaults.setValue(myMapView.region.span.latitudeDelta, forKey: "latDelta")
    defaults.setValue(myMapView.region.span.longitudeDelta, forKey: "longDelta")
}
```

Here's where it is set from the defaults in my viewDidLoad:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    if  let lat = defaults.valueForKey("lat"),
        let long = defaults.valueForKey("long"),
        let latDelta = defaults.valueForKey("latDelta"),
        let longDelta = defaults.valueForKey("longDelta")

    {
        let center: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat as! Double, long as! Double)
        let span: MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(latDelta as! Double, longDelta as! Double)
        let region: MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(center, span)
        myMapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    }
}
```

However, when I open the app again, the region isn't shown as it was when the app was closed. The values that aren't saved correctly seem to be incremented by a constant value each time I close and reopen. What's going on?

I switched to using a dictionaryForKey approach, and here's the resulting dictionary upon 3 successive loads, without changing the map region at all:

```
["long": -95.78, "latDelta": 76.06, "lat": 37.13, "longDelta": 61.27]
["long": -95.78, "latDelta": 88.18, "lat": 31.93, "longDelta": 76.82]
["long": -95.78, "latDelta": 100.69, "lat": 25.71, "longDelta": 86.56]
```

The long value is saved properly, but the other 3 are behaving strangely.

Answer (score 1):

Another Swift option (in **Swift 5**), abstracting the code into an extension on the region struct.

Here's an extension on the region struct that allows you to write it from multiple places:

```
extension MKCoordinateRegion {
  public func write(toDefaults defaults:UserDefaults, withKey key:String) {
    let locationData = [center.latitude, center.longitude,
                        span.latitudeDelta, span.longitudeDelta]
    defaults.set(locationData, forKey: key)
  }

  public static func load(fromDefaults defaults:UserDefaults, withKey key:String) -> MKCoordinateRegion? {
    guard let region = defaults.object(forKey: key) as? [Double] else { return nil }
    let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: region[0], longitude: region[1])
    let span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: region[2], longitudeDelta: region[3])
    return MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: span)
  }
}
```

Using the above extension requires only the following code in a view controller that contains the map view:

```
private let kMapRegion = "region"

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
  if let region = MKCoordinateRegion.load(fromDefaults: UserDefaults.standard, withKey: kMapRegion) {
    mapView.region = region
  }
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
  mapView.region.write(toDefaults: UserDefaults.standard, withKey: kMapRegion)
}
```

*(UserDefaults after iOS 12 no longer needs `synchronize`)*

Answer (score 0):

You can save NSDictionary Data directly like as following.

let locationData = ["lat":0.22222,
                            "lng":0.33333,
                            "D_lat":0.0001,
                            "D_lng":0.0001]
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(locationData, forKey: "location")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()

And Otherwise you can get NSDicationary Data like as following.

let savedLocation = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().dictionaryForKey("location")

or

let savedLocation = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().dataForKey("location") as? NSDictionary

Comment: I used this approach but I'm still having the same problem. I edited my question to show you the saved values I'm getting when I load my view.

Comment: That's very wired issue then, you need to debug first of all. when map is loaded, it will be called the region change function.

Comment: FYI, you have to use double value for the location data.

Comment: Thanks for your help. You helped me realize that the problem might be with using the regionDidChangeAnimated function. I moved the NSUserDefaults saving to the viewWillDisappear function and it works.

Answer (score 0):

You'd better use

NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setDouble(locationData, forKey: "locationData") & NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()

when you save location data.

But user this

NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().doubleForKey("locationData")

when you get location data.

Comment: There is no need for synchronize

Answer (score 0):

I realized that the problem comes when saving the region center and span in the regionDidChangeAnimated function. This leads to unpredictable results. A better place to save is in the viewWillDisappear function:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    let locationData = ["lat":myMapView.centerCoordinate.latitude
        , "long":myMapView.centerCoordinate.longitude
        , "latDelta":myMapView.region.span.latitudeDelta
        , "longDelta":myMapView.region.span.longitudeDelta]
    defaults.setObject(locationData, forKey: "location")
}
```